# Clojure Gloss - codec for Variable Byte Integer from MQTT protocol spec

Tags: clojure, mqtt, gloss

I am developing MQTT server in Clojure. I use [Gloss](https://github.com/ztellman/gloss) to parse binary data. However, I'm stuck with [Variable Byte Integer](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901011), not sure how to create codec for this. My gut feeling it should use `header` frame somehow, but I'm not sure how to put it together. So my questions are: 1. Is it possible to represent this as Gloss codec, or I should use some other approach? 2. Can you please provide codec for this? Thanks!

Comment: I want to be contributer. Can you share your code with me ?

Comment: I just started working on it, didn't publish yet

Comment: Here's the repo https://github.com/selentium/clj-mqtt

Comment: Why did you choose  Clojure language to code the mqtt ? @VladimirKadalashvili

Comment: Just want to practice with Clojure @SefaUn

Comment: could you code mqtt protocol ? @VladimirKadalashvili

Answer (score 1):

Reading the docs, it looks like you'll need to define something new to process the VBI encoding.

Since Gloss appears to expect only fixed-length representations, your algorithm will probably need to accept a block of bytes with a VBI at the beginning, then decode the VBI and return

1. the decoded value
2. the remaining bytes

The bytes from (2) can then be input to Gloss as normal.  If the VBI is not the first item in the overall input, you can strip off any leading bytes using Gloss or any other means.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating custom codec for Gloss https://github.com/selentium/clj-mqtt/blob/master/src/clj_mqtt/varint.clj